# How to change raw pointer to unique_ptr in container of pointers wrapped by boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, boost-variant

[Live code example](https://repl.it/repls/GigaBrokenSolution#main.cpp)

I am trying to hold a variant of pointers to templated versions of a base class in a vector. The `boost::variant` of pointers happens to be contained in a struct. It works fine if these pointers are raw pointers, but things start going wrong when I change them to `unique_ptr`.

```
struct Sayer {

  struct Category {
    using GetterVariant = boost::variant<
      //Getter<string>*, // works OK
      //Getter<double>*, // ...
      //Getter<int>*     // ...
      unique_ptr<Getter<string>>,
      unique_ptr<Getter<double>>,
      unique_ptr<Getter<int>>
    >;
    Category(GetterVariant g) :
      getter(g)
    {}
    GetterVariant getter;
  };

  vector<Category> categories;

  template <typename G>
  void addGetter() {
    categories.emplace_back(new G()); // allocate here, transfer ownership to Sayer::categories
  }

};
```

Compiler error:

```
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1627:28: error: no matching member
      function for call to 'initialize'
              initializer::initialize(
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1798:9: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization
      'boost::variant<std::unique_ptr<Getter<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
      std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >,
      std::default_delete<Getter<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
      std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >,
      std::unique_ptr<Getter<double>, std::default_delete<Getter<double> > >,
      std::unique_ptr<Getter<int>, std::default_delete<Getter<int> > >
      >::convert_construct<AgeGetter *>' requested here
        convert_construct( detail::variant::move(operand), 1L);

...

main.cpp:54:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<Sayer::Category, std::allocator<Sayer::Category>
      >::emplace_back<AgeGetter *>' requested here
    categories.emplace_back(new G());
               ^
main.cpp:65:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'Sayer::addGetter<AgeGetter>' requested here
  sayer.addGetter<AgeGetter>();

...

/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:115:24: note: candidate
      function not viable: no known conversion from 'typename
      ::boost::move_detail::remove_reference<AgeGetter *&>::type'
      (aka 'AgeGetter *') to 'std::unique_ptr<Getter<int>,
      std::default_delete<Getter<int> > >' for 2nd argument
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:149:17: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
    static void initialize();
```

How do I set this up so that the memory ownership is in the container?

Comment: Here's a MWE with reduced context but hopefully makes it easier to spot the problem(s): https://repl.it/repls/GigaBrokenSolution#main.cpp Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

First, you have to move `g` in the `Category` Constructor, since a variant is non-copyable if any of its members is non-copyable.

Second, while every conversion in the chain `AgeGetter*` to `Getter<int>*` to `std::unique_ptr<Getter<int>>` to `Category` is implicit, C++ only does a limited number of implicit conversions. So basically this chain is too long and you can fix it for example by using `emplace_back(std::make_unique<G>())` instead of `emplace_back(new G())`.

Also, this is safer, since if `emplace_back` throws (which it can), the `new G()` would not be deleted and hence leak. But the destructor `unique_ptr` returned by `std::make_unique<G>()` would be called if `emplace_back` throws and hence there would be no leak. You should always try to avoid raw `new` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense now. https://repl.it/repls/OvalAmpleEditors#main.cpp